# Hide element outside of container without overflow: hidden

Tags: jquery, css, positioning

I want to hide an element when it moves out of it's container. But I have 1 restriction: I cannot use `overflow: hidden;` as a permanent style in my container.

Here is a link to what I need:

http://jsfiddle.net/WVYpg/

I was wondering if there is a way to accomplish it doing something like dissapearing while it is going out? ... probably giving temporary `overflow: hidden` while it finishes the animation.

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/uhxAE/

Answer (score 5):

```
$().ready( function(){
  $( "#hide-span" ).click( function(){
    $( ".contained" ).animate( {
        left: "-250",opacity:"0"
    }, 1000 );
  } );
} );​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/WVYpg/2/)

or

```
$().ready( function(){
$( "#hide-span" ).click( function(){
    $( ".contained" ).animate( {
        left: "-250"
    }, 1000 );
    $( ".contained" ).fadeOut(200);
 } );
} );​
```

[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/WVYpg/4/)

Comment: Althought this option gives me the final solution (it moves and hides the element outside of it's container), it doesn't provide the effect i'm looking for. What I'm really looking for is hiding it while it is going out.

Comment: @Tales: What do you mean by hiding ? This is visually hiding it while it is going out. If you actually want to hide it as in `.hide()` your CSS gets messed up and your button moves to the top of your container.

Comment: Well, you gave me a good idea. Starting with the opacity example i made a custom function that adds overflow: hidden to the container element, starts the animation and after it is finished it gives opacity: 0 to the contained element and then removes the overflow: hidden from the container. I will post the example below, but this is the link to your example: http://jsfiddle.net/WVYpg/3/

Answer (score 2):

You can fake it by absolutely positioning an opaque element with higher `z-index` at the point where the element is moving to [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/WkBfu/), but that's not easy if there is already other content there.

Comment: It is a good idea, using the mask, but you're right, in the live code i cannot use it. But maybe for a future project this idea will work.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `z-index` of the container you are moving to be less than the container it is moving out of and that should provide the effect you're looking for.

Comment: I tried that, but didn't work. Added .container{ z-index: 100; } .contained{ z-index: 0; } and i also added body{ z-index: 200; } but the contained element remains visible;

Answer (score 0):

Using afshin's idea about the opacity, i figured it out. This is my complete code: (which you can find in here: http://jsfiddle.net/WVYpg/3/)

CSS:

```
body{
    background: #0000ff;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
div.container{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: #c3f1d3;
    margin: 50px auto;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 50;
/*    overflow: hidden; */
}
div.contained{
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #ff6600;
    margin: 50px auto 0px auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
span.text-to-hide{
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #0ec;
    width: 175px;
    font: bold 12px/20px "Trebuchet MS", Arial;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 75px auto;
    padding: 0px;
}
p{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 0px;
}
input{
    width: 100px;
    font: bold 12px/20px "Trebuchet MS", Arial;
}
.ohidden{
    overflow: hidden;
}​
```

​
jQuery:

```
/* $().ready( function(){
    $( "#hide-span" ).click( function(){
        $( ".container" ).css( "overflow", "hidden" );
        $( ".contained" ).animate( {
            left: "-250"
        }, 1000, function(){
            $( ".contained" ).css( "opacity", "0" );
            $( ".container").css( "overflow" ); 
        } );
    } );
} );​ */
$().ready( function(){
    $( "#hide-span" ).click( function(){
        $( ".container" ).addClass( "ohidden" );
        $( ".contained" ).animate( {
            left: "-250"
        }, 1000, function(){
            $( ".contained" ).css( "opacity", "0" );
            $( ".container").removeClass( "ohidden" ); 
        } );
    } );
} );​
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="container" id="container">
        <div class="contained">
            <span class="text-to-hide">Move this text outside of container and hide it</span>
        </div>
        <p><input type="button" value="Hide span" id="hide-span"></p>
    </div>
</body>​
```

Comment: You don't need opacity. The moment you added `$( ".container" ).css( "overflow", "hidden" ); it looks no different`with or without opacity. In addition you have redundant code, seeing you already added the overflow CSS at the start of the function you do not need to add the line again inside the callback. Though the line you have in your callback `$( ".container").css( "overflow" );` doesn't actually do anything at all anyway. Theoretically your entire callback is redundant and not needed all you need is your first additional line :)

Comment: I think you're wrong. At the begining of the script i use: $( ".container" ).css( "overflow", "hidden" ); I give the overflow property to be able to do the animation. When the animation is finished and as i stated earlier, I cannot have a permanent overflow property on the container I have to deal with it removing the property from the container, but before i make it's boundaries visible, i need to hide everything outside, that's the $( ".contained" ).css( "opacity", "0" );. At the end the $( ".container").css( "overflow" ); at the end of the code, I'm removing that property, not adding it.

Comment: Sorry, what I was trying to say is: Your callback is not working as you might expect it. The `overflow: hidden` is **not** removed. Please run your fiddle and in chrome for example use the debugger tools and check your HTML which shows you that overflow hidden is still there. You can also test it by simply removing line that sets the opacity which theoretically should have the div visible in the end but it doesn't as overflow hidden is still applied to the container after the call is done.

Comment: You were right, the code was updated here: http://jsfiddle.net/WVYpg/6/ in this new version i have created a class called .ohidden and when the animation starts i add the class to the container and remove it when the animation is finished. I think now i can say it's working. I also left the $( ".contained" ).css( "opacity", "0" ); commented to be able to see the effect.